# Stripe not displaying input fields Woo Commerce

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe payment gateway in my client’s woo commerce website.
But when I tested in Live mode, input fields are not allowing to add the card details. When I checked it displays:

<!– a Stripe Element will be inserted here. –>”

Comment: Welcome! This question could use more detail to make it easier for someone to answer. For instance, try updating your question to answer questions like: How did you integrate Stripe? How are you rendering the page to accept payment? Are there any errors logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are pretty good the browser console shows some Javascript errors that are causing the Stripe Elements to not render properly, so I'd suggest having a look at your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Check the details of the browser console, if there are any errors fix them first

Also make sure that you are on the checkout page, i.e. the `is_checkout()` function returns true. If you have custom checkout page you can use `woocommerce_is_checkout` filter to return true according to your code, and then Stripe fields will be initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue where the input fields were not being displayed.

To resolve this, please follow these steps:

1. Check the console for any JavaScript errors and fix them before proceeding.
2. Avoid using the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode directly in your PHP scripts like `echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');`. And make sure to add the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode as the content. Then, call
   the `the_content()` or `echo get_the_content()`.
   This is necessary because the WooCommerce Stripe
   plugin checks for the presence of the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode
   within the content.